# How to make a program that can decide which function should be run with the passing data?

Tags: javascript, function, object

I have worked with this way last time with an another function and it was working good!

but when i used it here in the code below,

```
function upComingSchedule(scheduleValue='01',startDate='Jun/27/21',options={}){

  var orderDate = new Date(startDate);
  
  var loadFnc = loadFncName(scheduleValue);

  /**---------------------------------------------------
   * array of lastDate & lastvalue of passed slot in db
   * last ={date: someDate,value:someValue}
  ----------------------------------------------*/
  var last = getLastSchedule(scheduleValue);

  if(loadFnc=="customWeek"){
    loadFnc(orderDate,options)
  }else{
    loadFnc(orderDate,last)
  }

}
```

it always show the error: loadFnc is not a function.

```
function loadFncName(scheduleValue){
  
  var navigation = {
    "01" : "upComingAlt",
    "001" : "upComingE3D",
    custom : "customWeek"
  }

  return navigation[scheduleValue];
}
```

I think there is something I'm doing wrong. Please explain!

Comment: In the `if` statement you treat `loadFnc` as a string and directly afterwards you treat it as a function. You will need something (e.g. an object) that maps the strings to the functions, and then get the function (not the function name) with that

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked! I was using string in the navigation obj.

Answer (score 0):

Is difficult to test but only by looking I can say you are passing to `loadFnc` a function that accept only one argument. So when you call loadFnc with two argument you throw an error.
Try to declare `loadFncName` with two arguments.

Comment: First of, the OP is not passing a function to `loadFnc`, the OP passes the result of a function call to `loadFnc` (in this case a string). Secondly, javascript doesn't care if the argument count matches the definition. If it doesn't match it simply sets the remaining parameters to undefined. It won't throw an Error because of that

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @A-A.

just remove "" from the navigation to return the actual function not a string named same as the function!

```
function upComingSchedule(scheduleValue="01",startDate='Jun/27/21',options={}){

  var orderDate = new Date(startDate);
  
  var loadFnc = loadFncName(scheduleValue);

  /**---------------------------------------------------
   * array of lastDate & lastvalue of passed slot in db
   * last ={date: someDate,value:someValue}
  ----------------------------------------------*/
  var last = getLastSchedule(scheduleValue);

  if(scheduleValue=="custom"){
    loadFnc(orderDate,options)
  }else{
     loadFnc(orderDate,last)
  }

}

function loadFncName(scheduleValue){
  
  var navigation = {
    "01" : upComingAlt,
    "001" : upComingE3D,
    "custom" : customWeek
  }

  return navigation[scheduleValue];
}
```